# Inversion of $\cap$ and $\cup$ in set identities

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there an elementary argument that replacing every $\cap$ with $\cup$ and $\cup$ with $\cap$ in a set identity involving only intersections and unions results again in a valid identity?

Strictly speaking, the only facts available at this point are the distributivity identities for $\cap$ and $\cup$ and $A\setminus(B \cap C) = (A\setminus B) \cup (A\setminus C)$ and its dual for arbitrary sets, but complements/universe weren't introduced nor were the De Morgan laws

Comment: The latter **is** De Morgan's law. Take $A$ to be the universe.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. The universe as a concept hasn't been introduced, and you're not supposed to go around taking complements in that sense, is what I'm saying.

Comment: you can use the DeMorgan laws without the need of an universe, just represent the complement respect to the union of all considered sets

Comment: I'm not sure how to make substitution work in that case. If I have an identity, say $A \cap B = B \cap A$, and I can take complements, I get $\overline{A \cap B} = \overline{B \cap A}$, then $\overline{A} \cup \overline{B} = \overline{B} \cup \overline{A}$. Then I can simply substitute the complements of any sets I care about for the variables and get the commutativity of union. But if I use the union of the respective sets, I'll end up needing to factor it into the substitution, and it doesn't simplify to what I need

Answer (score 1):

Here is a laborious approach that (sort of) sidesteps the universe issue.

Identify a set $A$ with its indicator function $1_A$ and replace expressions of the form $A \cap B$ by $1_A \land 1_B$ and similarly $A \cup B$ by $1_A \lor 1_B$.

Here is the sidestep, note that the indicator of the complement of a set $A$ is given by
$1_{A^c} = \lnot 1_A$.

Suppose we have a set identity of the form $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2$, where the $\alpha_k$
involve $\cap,\cup,$ and the symbols $A_1,A_2,...$. Using the above, find the equivalent Boolean expressions $\omega_1, \omega_1$, and from the identity we know that $\omega_1 = \omega_1$.

(Being a little pedantic, note that strictly speaking one has to apply the above to a specific point say $x$, to
have a Boolean expression. For example, a set formula $A \cap B$ is translated into
the function $x \mapsto 1_A(x) \land 1_B(x)$, so the get a bona fide Boolean expression
it needs to be evaluated at a specific point. However, since two functions are equal **iff** they are equal when applied to each point of their common domain, we can gloss over this point.)

Given a Boolean expression $\omega$ in the variables $1_{A_k}$, replace each variable by
the corresponding $1_{A_k^c}$, replace $\land$ by $\lor$ and $\lor$ by $\land$. Call the resulting expression $\omega^*$ (the dual).

Show (by induction on the expression depth) that $\omega^* = \lnot \omega$. (This is the key result and needs a little work.)

Then since $\omega_1^* = \lnot \omega_1 = \lnot \omega_2 = \omega_2^*$, we almost have the desired result.

The catch is that the corresponding expression involves the indicator functions of the complements of sets $A_k$, for example the identity $A \cap B = B \cap A$ becomes $1_{A^c} \lor 1_{B^c} = 1_{B^c} \lor 1_{A^c} $ and for the purposes of this question we are
(sort of) avoiding explicit universes (which would give $A^c \cup B^c = B^c \cup A^c$).

However, since the identity holds for any indicator functions, we can replace the $1_{A_k^c}$ by any other indicator function, in particular we can replace the $1_{A_k^c}$
by $1_{A_k}$ and the identity remains true and so, in the above example, we end up with
$A \cup B = B \cup A$.